# Error 107 Invalid JSON Parse Rested API - App Opens

Tags: php, curl, parse-platform

I am trying to work with the Parse Rested API to build a custom analytics panel.

When requesting the app opens, I am always getting the error

```
{"code":107,"error":"invalid JSON"}
```

when trying to request app opens.

Here is how I perform my cURL request:

```
$service_url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/events/AppOpened';
$appId = 'abc';
$restKey = 'efg';

$header = array( 
    "Content-Type: application/json",  
    "X-Parse-Application-Id: " . $appId,  
    "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: " . $restKey
);  


 $rest = curl_init();  
 curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_URL,$service_url);  
 curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_POST,1);  
 curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);  
 curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
 curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
 $response = curl_exec($rest);  
 echo $response;  
 print_r($response);  
 curl_close($rest);
```

When sending up an empty JSON object, Parse does not error anymore, instead returns me an empty JSON object.

Comment: Maybe API expects some JSON and from the code is obvious that you are not sending any JSON to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the documentation for your method [App-Open Analytics](https://parse.com/docs/rest#analytics) and as far as I can see it **expects at least empty JSON object** from you.

It is obvious from this part of their cUrl example

```
-d '{
    }' \
```

You can do the same from PHP using

```
curl_setopt($rest, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{}');
```

Comment: Hi Paul, many thanks for getting back to me. I forgot to mention I have already tried sending up an empty JSON object and have tried your PHP method, but strangely all I have returned, in my example, $response = {}. So Parse is returning an empty JSON object? Many thanks for your time and help.

Comment: @user3343388 Receiving empty JSON from the server is far more better than receiving JSON with error code and message. There is nothing written about return data on this method, but I suppose that it shouldn't return anything in response. It just tracks the activity (_AppOpened_ event in your case) and data about how much and frequent application was opened is available at app dashboard.

Comment: Send a request, obtain response without errors and check data at your dashboard, and you will know if its ok.

Comment: Thanks Paul, you've removed the error so have accepted the answer. Still have no data returned but that's a seperate issue. My Parse dashboard is full of thousands of app opens so the data is there, just an issue of finding out what i'm doing wrong! Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user3343388 Thanks! Try to write in Parse.com support, you will get answer faster from them ;)

Comment: Will do! Thanks once again.